# Perl Regular Expression: Skip a few columns in CSV file

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to read a csv file and retrieve only a few columns.
However, the number of columns in each like is quite large (around 100 columns)

The problem here is I try to read the content of column 1,2,3,4,5,60, etc.
I just want to ask if there is a way to skip column 6-59 in RegExp so I can read column 60.

Here is my attempt so far for 1 line, semicolon(;) is the seperator

```
if ($line =~ /^([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);[[^;]+;]{59};([^;]+)/) {
    print "$1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6\n";
}
```

But the code doesn't work. I will be grateful if someone can help me do this.

Comment: Some sample data or information about your data would help. Like can there be quoted `;` or not ...

Comment: a line can look like this {a;b;c;d;e;...;z;...}, "..." means there are multiple elements. e.g.: "..." = "f;g;h;i;j" that I don't need to retrieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use core module [`Text::ParseWords`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html)

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::ParseWords;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @words = parse_line( ";", 1, $_ );
    print join( ":", @words[ 0, 1, 4 ] ), "\n";
}

__DATA__
1;2;"3;4;5";6;7
```

This outputs:

```
1:2:7
```

In your particular case, after splitting the line in to an array, you can use `@words[0..4]` to print four elements or `$words[60]` to print the 61st element.

Comment: Hi, I used split() function and extract different columns out of it. But is it going to be slower than Regexp? I'm just getting myself familiar to Regular Expression.

Comment: @lightbringer `split` is going to be a lot faster than any `regex` based approach. The reason to use the module is because you stated in your comments that you could have nested `;` which should be treated as one. `parse_line` method will help you split the line at right delimiters. Ofcourse if your data is just simple `;` then you don't need the module.

Comment: @jaypal: Perl `split` is not particularly fast mostly due to the creation of the scalars. In this case, where you are going to discard most of the outputs a regexp could actually be faster.